# Javascript strict mode and versions

Tags: javascript

I want to use `let` in my code. Like so:

```
"use strict";

var b = 5;
for(let i =0;b > i; i++){
    alert(i);
}
```

This is working in Chrome and IE. But not in Firefox.

Wrapping my code in script tags with the type attribute set to "application/javascript;version=1.7" like so:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
```

This fixes the problem in Firefox, but breaks the code in Chrome and IE.
The error Firefox gives me when i execute the first code snippet:

> SyntaxError: let is a reserved identifier

Is there any way to support all browsers?

Comment: Iirc the `application/javascript;version=` was only a proposed solution to allowing new ES6 features without breaking compatibility. I don't think this is standard and [feature testing](https://github.com/getify/es-feature-tests) should be used instead:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using **let** unless you're using a transcoder/transpiler to convert your js to code that is currently widely supported.

Let became standard in ECMA-262 but it'll be several years before a large enough portion of visitors support it natively to use it.

The following have basic support for **let**, everything below will break:

1. Chrome 41+
2. Gecko 2.0
3. IE11
4. Opera 17+
5. Safari ??

The above browsers likely have inconsistent implementations at this point, so it's best to avoid it.

Check out [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) to transform.

Answer (score 1):

Let as defined in ES2015 (ES6) is not yet supported in Firefox. It has an old version of `let` that is non standard and works slightly differently.

The current way to support it in all browsers is to use a transpiler like [BabelJS](http://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Is there a better way than doing something like this?

`<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">if firefox.. code</script>`

`<script>normal code</script>`

Comment: @Mathijs that would not work please don't do it. In firefox `let` works differently than in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), use a transpiler.